# ADO.NET Entity Data Model refresh after incremental Db changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I am using VS 2013 Express for Web with ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

When updating the entity data model from database using 'refresh' tab option (seems you can only select one item though the heading says select objects plural) the usage seems unclear and I have noticed some issues.

Just two examples:

1. I changed a stored procedure so it returned the same number of fields but one field was of a slightly different type but the complex type never  changed.  I realise there can be an impact on client code but this simply did not change the complex type, everything stayed the same. However, removing the relevant elements from the model browser then readding the elments from the database back into the model did exactly what I expected.
2. I made some significant changes to two or three tables, attributes and one relationship but did bot change the table names.  Here again refresh had some very odd results, so I simply created a fresh model.

I am planning some more changes first change specifically I am adding a FK relationship that I forgot.

Is there any way to be sure of what is supported and what is not in terms of refresh.

Also I am concerned that if refresh fails and I so delete the two tables with the relationship, what impact will that have on temporarily orphaned tables and their relationships, and if when I regenerate the two tables their connections with the other tables will still work.  I guess it depends how the generated code works underneath.

I want to make these kinds of changes but avoid have to recreate the entire model.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The most guaranteed way of ensuring you always have the latest version is to select all (Ctrl A) delete, and then re-add everything from the model page.

I know it sounds like a pain but it's guaranteed to work as long as you haven't made any changes to the model from within Visual Studio.

The refresh doesn't always work.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.  So to be clear, you are suggesting I click any where in 'the browser model' then hit CTRL A then hit DELETE, right?  The only thing I every may do with the model in vs is move things in the diagram a bit and make calls into the code, no changes to the code.   The re-add bit, I normally right click model diagram select update model from db , I assume there will be no issues there after deleting the code, right?   I'll try it.  Thank you.

Comment: @hardya - yes, correct. All you are doing with the above is deleting the model and recreating it again from the db. It may sound extreme but it works for me and I've being doing it for years. Even with a very complicated db it only takes a few seconds.

Comment: OK, now I'm actually trying what I said and there appears to be no CTRL A feature in the model browser.  Where in the hierarchy or pane  do I initially click before CTRL A is available?  I'm presuming you don't mean CTRL A in the diagram, I would have thought that just removes from the diagram only, no?

Comment: I have deleted all from diagram and the store tables/views and the model entity types are now empty, but all the stored procedures, function imports and complex types are still present.  Provided the stored procedures has not changed do you know if integrity will be maintained if I leave those in place?  If not then is there a quick way to delete them each time?  Or just one by one?

Comment: @hardya - yes. Assuming it is only changes within the tables, then selecting all, deleting all then re-creating from the database will only re-create the tables - which is what you want presumably? If you want the procs etc, then you need to delete and re-create those also.